# CSS :hover being being aplied for children, but not for the element itself

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a simple CSS file with the following content:

```
button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-style: none;
  padding: 8px 16px 8px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #2a5788;
  color: white;
}

button :hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

In the HTML file, I have a simple button. The button style is being applied as expected, but, the :hover property is simply ignored. But, if I put something inside the button, like an icon, when the mouse is hover the icon, the icon background turns black.

```
<button>
    <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
    Adicionar Rastreio
</button>
```

[image: Blue button with text "Adicionar Rastreio" and a play icon. The mouse is hover the play icon and the icon background is black, but the button background is blue.]

I'm new to CSS, so I could be missing something.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Angular its just CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space `button :hover {`

[Read More](https://blog.novalistic.com/archives/2018/01/whitespace-in-css-selectors/)

```css
button {
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-style: none;
  padding: 8px 16px 8px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #2a5788;
  color: white;
}

button:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button>
    <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
    Adicionar Rastreio
</button>
```